# A Game Design Solution for mapping large property data sets with many mutations that can be applied.

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm having some trouble coming up with a sound design for what to me is a fairly tricky module. The actual business logic got me in a terrible mess, so I rephrased it into a more readily understandable form. I'm coding in C#, although I guess the actual design is language agnostic.

Imagine you're coding a simple fantasy roleplaying game. You have a player, who has some basic attributes. The player can equip some items, which may impact his attributes in some way. Items have one or more properties, which define which attributes are modified.

```
public Character
{
    public string charName;
    public int charStrength;
    public int charHitPoints;
    ...
    public List<Item> equippedItems;
}

public Item
{
    public string itemName;
    public List<ItemProperty> itemProperties;   
}

public ItemProperty
{
    public int propertyValue;
    public virtual void applyPropertyModification(Character charStatsToBeModified){}
}
```

Character data is in XML format:

```
<Character>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <BaseStrength>10</BaseStrength>
    <BaseHitPoints>100</BaseHitPoints>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Name>Short Sword</Name>
            <Properties>
                <Strength>10</Strength>
                <HitPoints>200</HitPoints>
            </Properties>
        </Item>
    </Items>
<Character>
```

I'm looking for a way to load a character data from XML which allows me to easily add X generic new character attributes (imagine 50 or so) and/or Y generic item Properties (imagine 100-150 or so).

My design thoughts:

Each possible character attribute gets added to the Character class as a new property. May get unwieldy as number of attributes grows large. Each possible Item Property is added as its own subclass of ItemProperty, with an appropriate `applyPropertyModification` method.

```
public Strength : ItemProperty
{
    public override void applyPropertyModification(Character charStatsToBeModified)
    {
        charStatsToBeModified.charStrength += this.propertyValue
    }
}
```

This does seem like a large amount of excessive code, especially since all the overwridden method is doing is determining which character attribute should be modified.

The ItemProperty is to be created using reflection, with the element XML tags corresponding to appropriate ItemProperty subclasses (alternative would be a 100 condition switch I think?).

Is my general design sound, or am I approaching this is the wrong direction? I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure this out by myself, but I'm convinced there is a neater way to do this. Also, if this question is unclear at all, or rambling, please let me know and I will try to clarify/rephrase. Thanks.

Comment: So you resisted the urge to refactor the object when it got to 10 properties.  And 20.  And 50.  And 100.  And 200.  Now its hundreds, kinda late to do anything about it, isn't it?  Bolting some kind of reflection scheme on top of it will considerably add to the suck.  Not just fat and unmaintainable, add slow and unreliable.  Don't do it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me - I've not created anything at all yet. I'm tyring to come up with a solid design for an object exactly to prevent it becoming fat and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok a few people here were on the right path... but nobody hit the nail on the head so here it goes.  It seems like you started on the right path but need to take it a bit further.  I wrote this with comments in the code to let it do a bit of the explanation for me.

Here goes:

```
//So you have a character...
public class Character
{
    //You know you ALWAYS need Raw Attribs in a game
    private Dictionary<string, Attrib> _rawAttributes;
    //You know you will always need a record of modified attribs
    private Dictionary<string, Attrib> _modifiedAttributes;
    //And while your at it, take a light optimization to not have to recalculate everytime
    private bool _areModifiedAttribsCurrent { get; set; }
    //A character has gear! This is what makes the world go around
    public List<Equipment> Equipment { get; private set; }

    //You don't want to give public access to setting gear, this should be controlled.
    //You'll want to do more as far as remove / change... but this'll get you started
    public void AddEquipment(Equipment e)
    {
        Equipment.Add(e);
        _areModifiedAttribsCurrent = false;
    }

    //And a way to add attribs and set base values..
    //once again, you will want more but this will get you started
    public void AddAttribute(Attrib x)
    {
        _rawAttributes.Add(x.Name, x);
    }

    //Finally you want a way to fetch the modified attribs
    //Keep in mind you need to do the copy dance in the  apply to not upset your 
    //base stats.
    public Dictionary<string, Attrib> FetchModifiedAttributes()
    {
        if (!_areModifiedAttribsCurrent)
        {
            var traceAttribs = _rawAttributes;
            foreach (var e in Equipment.OrderBy(x => x.ApplyOrder))
            {
                traceAttribs = e.ApplyModifiers(traceAttribs);
            }
            _modifiedAttributes = traceAttribs;
        }

        return _modifiedAttributes;
    }
}

//Attrib, pretty simple.. Could go away but we all know attribs have effects so don't even start down that path
//You WILL need this class later on... but right now it looks pretty meaningless.
public class Attrib
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

//GEAR... yes, this is what all RPG lovers love... 
//Grind for that awesome gear!
public class Equipment
{
    //Ok so I put in some stuff unrelated to your problem but you need a name right?!
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //What order does gear effect stats... this is important if you do more than flat modifiers.
    public int ApplyOrder { get; set; }
    //What modifiers does this gear have?!
    public List<Modifier> ItemModifiers { get; set; }
    //Aha.... let the gear apply its modifiers to an attrib dictionary... I knew I loved OO for some reason
    public Dictionary<string, Attrib> ApplyModifiers(Dictionary<string, Attrib> inParams)
    {
        //Copy / Clone... Whatever you want to call it this is important as to not 
        //unintentionally screw up yoru base collection.
        var response = new Dictionary<string, Attrib>();
        foreach (var m in ItemModifiers)
        {
            //If we have this attrib, keep going
            if (inParams.ContainsKey(m.TargetName))
            {
                //If this is the first time the response ran into it, add it
                if (!response.ContainsKey(m.TargetName))
                {
                    response.Add(m.TargetName, inParams[m.TargetName]);
                }

                //And wait what's this... let the Modifier apply it!?  
                //yes... pass it down again... you'll see why in a second.
                m.Apply(response[m.TargetName]);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}

//A modifier... what the!?
//Yep... abstraction is key to maintainable and expandable code
public class Modifier
{
    public string TargetName { get; set; }
    public decimal ModifierValue { get; set; }
    //The other stuff is kind of pointless... but this is where the magic happens... All in a modifier type.
    public ModifierType ModifierType { get; set; }
    //Let the modifier apply it's own values... off the type... yea
    //I did that on purpose ;-)
    public void Apply(Attrib a)
    {
        a.Value = ModifierType.ApplyModifier(this, a.Value);
    }
}

//Decoration... Wonderful
//This base class gives you a interface to work with... Hell, it could be an interface but I decided
//to type abstract today.
public abstract class ModifierType
{
    public abstract string ModifierName { get; }
    public abstract decimal ApplyModifier(Modifier m, decimal InitialValue);
}

//A concrete type of ModifierType... This is what determines how the modifier value is applied.
//This gives you more flexibility than hard coding modifier types.  If you really wanted to you could
//serialize these and store lambda expressions in the DB so you not only have type driven logic, you could have
//data driven behavior.
public class FlatModifier : ModifierType
{
    //The names can be really handy if you want to expose calculations to players.
    public override string ModifierName { get { return "Flat Effect"; } }
    //And finally... let the calculation happen!  Time to bubble back up!
    public override decimal ApplyModifier(Modifier m, decimal InitialValue)
    {
        return InitialValue + m.ModifierValue;
    }
}
```

Let your objects do the work for you.  I know it's coming from XML but let them deserialize into your objects and call a few choice methods to handle it.  This keeps a few of the nagging issues at bay like C# is by reference and all that annoying stuff.  Also it keeps from redundant processing passes from jacking up your object graph.

Let me know if you have any questions... I'm bored tonight.

Comment: That is fantastic. I'd upvote this 10x if I could. Reading something like this makes me realise that I've a long way to go.

Comment: When a question asker actually says thank you is why I do it.  :-)  Thank YOU for providing an interesting question that in fact alleviated my  bordom last night :-)  I'll be posting a lot along these lines on my blog.  Hit me up from my profile :-).

Answer (score 1):

So you `Character` type has hundreds of properties / fields, and you want to simply set the value of those fields based on the XML element name?

The easiest solution would be to simply read the XML element and construct a `Dictionary<string, string>` that contains your values. Then, for each element of your dictionary, if your `Character` type exposes a matching property / field from your dictionary key, attempt to set the value of the property via reflection with that value. AKA:

```
Character someCharacter = // Create your character
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = // Load XML and transform
var properties = someCharacter.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myDictionary)
{
    var matchingProperty = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName.ToLower() == kvp.Key.ToLower());

    if(matchingProperty != null)
    {
        matchingProperty.SetValue(character, kvp.Value, null); // make sure to type convert if necesary here, since kvp.Value is a string, etc
    }
}
```

You write the code once, and thus you can add properties to your XML / Object and be able to override as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using refection. Change the xml to match something like this

```
<Items>
  <Item name="Short Sword">
    <Properties>
      <Property name="Strength" type="int">10<Property>               
      <Propery name="HitPoints" type="int">200</HitPoints>
    </Properties>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Parse it based on the attributes into a `Dictionary<String,Dynamic>`, implement the indexer

e.g.

```
private Dictionary<String, Dynamic> _properties = new Dictionary<String,Dynamic>();

public dynamic this[Strng argIndex]
{
  get {return _properties[argIndex];}
}
```

Carry this forward in to characters and such and you can do fun stuff like

```
characters["Fred"].Hitpoints = characters["Fred"].Items["Short Sword"].Hitpoints * characters["Fred"].Experience["Blades"]
```

Once you've defined the propertybag class (`Dictionary<String,Dynamic>` thingy) a property can be a propertybag.

NB it will be a bit slower, as basically this is using .net's version of Ducktyping, it uses late binding but it's extremely flexible, if you want to pay the price, for sirry ellors at run time.

Comment: Dynamics essentially are reflection... The DLR is just an abstraction over the Reflection libraries with limited optimization over intelligent use of Reflection itself.

Comment: @VulgarBinary, That's like saying OO is simlply procedural in another guise. It's true, but misses the point. You'd have to write one heck of a lot of code to achieve the "fun" line of code with vanilla reflection

Comment: Apparently our definitions of "fun" are drastically different ;-)  Regardless... This problem is solvable without delving into reflection or dynamics.  It's too great of a performance hit from the perspective of large collections of data and lots of repeat processing.  If the true target is game-like you need snappy efficiency you just won't get from Run Time logic that the DLR provides.  (See my solution below)

Comment: Point taken, though I wasn't proposing a solution from a performance perspective, the environments I work in flexibility/descriptive power is far more valuable. Still three different answers all with their own merits, can't be bad.